# Почему может не работать метод "split"?

Tags: java, android

Применяю так:

```
String s = "01.02.2003";
String[] arr = s.split(".");
Log.i("MyLog", "arr.length: " + arr.length);
```

Результат:

```
arr.length: 0;
```

Проверяю:

```
if (s.contains("."))
    Log.i("MyLog", "true");
else
    Log.i("MyLog", "false");
```

Результат:

```
true
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Символ `.` используется в регулярных выражениях для обозначения *любого символа*

Поэтому нужно этот символ экранировать: `s.split("\\.")`

Comment: Да, дело было в этом. Спасибо.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста!

Comment: моя правка правда была такая плохая, что её стоило откатить?

Comment: Я написал, что забыл где и для чего используется, а вы взяли и за меня все написали.

Comment: И в результате чего получился не мой ответ!

Comment: После того как вы нажали ответить, ответ перестал быть вашим, он принадлежит сообществу. Правки уточняющие или объясняющие вполне оправданы. @diraria абсолютно прав. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/editing

Comment: Ответ никак не принадлежит сообществу и могу удалить когда захочу.  Это мой ответ с изьянами и с недочетами. Если кто то решит ответить более точнее, к примеру @diraria, сам напишет ответ.

Comment: @TITAN, вы не правы, почитайте по ссылке. `Если вам не нравится то, что ваш вклад в сообщество может редактироваться другими пользователями, возможно, вам нужен другой сайт` Цитата из правил